# How to add other elements in adf bar chart

Tags: java, tags, bar-chart, oracle-adf

I need to add two `inputDates` and a `commandbutton` in a *bar chart*, so that I could query the *chart* and refresh with the reflected changes of the new query data.

How can I achieve this, does the *adf bar chart* provide special *tags* to include *tags* in the *chart* other than its *tags*?

I want to put the *components* below the *title* and above the *graph*.

Answer (score 0):

You don't put the components inside the chart. Rather you take a layout component like a panelForm and have the two items and the chart all in the same layout component.